# Install VueRouter with Vue-Cli Webpack

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I created a fresh project using the vue-cli command:

```
vue init webpack myapp
```

I am trying to add the `vue-router` to handle routes but I am having trouble.

Here is my `main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App'

var Foo = Vue.extend({
    template: '<p>This is foo!</p>'
})

var Bar = Vue.extend({
    template: '<p>This is bar!</p>'
})

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter()

router.map({
  '/foo': {
    component: Foo
  },
  '/bar': {
    component: Bar
  }
})

router.start(App, '#app')

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: { App }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Here is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>shivaminyanim.com</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app></app>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Hello App!</h1>
    <p>
      <!-- use v-link directive for navigation. -->
      <a v-link="{ path: '/foo' }">Go to Foo</a>
      <a v-link="{ path: '/bar' }">Go to Bar</a>
    </p>
    <!-- route outlet -->
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Whatever I do I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. Right now I don't get any console errors but the browser just displays

> Cannot GET /foo

for every route respectively.

I am currently using

> "vue": "^1.0.21"
>   "vue-router": "^0.7.13",

How can I get started with vue-router?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add router to your bootstrapped Vue instance in `main.js`. For example like this:

Vue 2.0 and Vue-router 2.0

```
new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Vue 1.0 and Vue-router < 2.0

```
router.start({
  components: { App }
}, '#app')
```

Comment: Hey @Primoz, I am sure you are right that I need to include the router. However, I am still getting the same error so it looks like there may be something else wrong. I'll update the question to include the `router.start`. I'm pretty sure you should be able to reproduce the error if you follow the same steps as me. Any more help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which version of `vue` and `vue-router`are you running ? Is the default root working (e.g. `http://localhost:8080`) and just subroute note like `/foo`?

Comment: I just updated the question to include that. the default route is not working. (It did before I added `vue-router` stuff to my `main.js`

Comment: I don't think you need this part in your main.js... `new Vue({el: 'body', components: { App }}).$mount('#app')`. Just bootstrap your app as you see in my answer above with `router.start()`

Comment: we may be getting closer, now i have the error `
cannot find element '#app'`

Comment: Well that was bc it was a logic circle. Switched it to body and now we are good. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad it helped!